# Draw a vertical arrow using canvas 2d

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a vertical arrow using canvas and javascript. i am able to draw one with arrow head upwards but finding difficulty in placing arrow head at the bottom.

The code i am trying

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>

  <script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    drawArrow(ctx, 300, 300, 300, 200);
    
    function drawArrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
      const headlen = 10; // length of head in pixels
      const angle = Math.atan2(toy - fromy, tox - fromx);
      
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
      context.lineTo(tox, toy);
      context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
      context.moveTo(tox, toy);
      context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
      context.stroke();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

which is drawing a an arrow like this
[image]

What i need is the same arrow head which will be placed at the bottom downwards.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The arrow generation is already dynamic in the code you've found. All you need to do is change the coordinates of the start and end position.

Change

```
drawArrow(ctx, 300, 300, 300, 200);
```

To

```
drawArrow(ctx, 300, 200, 300, 300);
```

Here's a working example:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
drawArrow(ctx, 300, 200, 300, 300);

function drawArrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
  const headlen = 10; // length of head in pixels
  const angle = Math.atan2(toy - fromy, tox - fromx);

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
  context.lineTo(tox, toy);
  context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
  context.moveTo(tox, toy);
  context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The args just need to be switched around, because you are passing origin x, origin y, destination x, destination y. The X args stay the same, but y just needs to have an origin less than the destination:

```
drawArrow(ctx, 300, 100, 300, 300);
```

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
    drawArrow(ctx, 300, 100, 300, 300);
    
    function drawArrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
      const headlen = 10; // length of head in pixels
      const angle = Math.atan2(toy - fromy, tox - fromx);
      
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
      context.lineTo(tox, toy);
      context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
      context.moveTo(tox, toy);
      context.lineTo(tox - headlen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toy - headlen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
      context.stroke();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```